# Passing substring parameters to awk

Tags: shell

I need to split a file and rename it accordingly using awk command. I'm trying to use the substring command and pass a parameter to awk command but it fails.

```
for file in *.csv
do
  split -n 3 -d -a 2 "$file" "$file--"
  for each in $(seq -w 2 10)
  do
        echo $file--$each

  awk -v filestem= ${$file--$each:2:5} '{filename = filestem; print >> filename}' $file--$each
  done
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options

1. Apply the substring inside awk

   ```
   $ awk -v filestem="$file--$each" \
       '{filename = substr(filestem, 3, 6);print >> filename}'
   ```
2. Set `$file--$each` to a variable, then substring that variable

   ```
   $ filestem="$file--$each"
   $ awk -v filestem="${filestem:2:5}" \
       '{filename = filestem; print >> filename}'
   ```